# How to mock React component methods with jest and enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a react component(this is simplified in order to demonstrate the issue):

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
    handleNameInput = (value) => {
        this.searchDish(value);
    };

    searchDish = (value) => {
      //Do something
    }

    render() {
        return(<div></div>)
    }
}
```

Now I want to test that `handleNameInput()` calls `searchDish` with the provided value.

In order to do this I would like to create a [jest mock function](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/api.html#jestfnimplementation) that replaces the component method.

Here is my test case so far:

```
it('handleNameInput', () => {
   let wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent/>);
   wrapper.searchDish = jest.fn();
   wrapper.instance().handleNameInput('BoB');
   expect(wrapper.searchDish).toBeCalledWith('BoB');
})
```

But all I get in the console is `SyntaxError`:

> SyntaxError
>
> ```
>   at XMLHttpRequest.open (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xmlhttprequest.js:458:15)
>   at run_xhr (node_modules/browser-request/index.js:215:7)
>   at request (node_modules/browser-request/index.js:179:10)
>   at DishAdmin._this.searchDish (src/main/react/components/DishAdmin.js:155:68)
>   at DishAdmin._this.handleNameInput (src/main/react/components/DishAdmin.js:94:45)
>   at Object.<anonymous> (src/main/react/tests/DishAdmin.test.js:122:24)
> ```

So my question is, how do I properly mock component methods with enzyme?

Comment: What's the syntax error?

Comment: Added to the question :)

Comment: Without knowing precisely what the source is it's impossible to help--I don't see any syntax errors in the code you posted.

Comment: the syntax error comes from wrapper.searchDish = jest.fn(); After changing this line the error does not appear any more, so I am guessing that the mock function is not getting assigned correctly. But I do not know what the correct way is, and whether or not this is available at all. Hence the question

Comment: Isn't `searchDish` on the `instance()`, not the wrapper?

Comment: I don't understand why a function named `searchDish` is being called here. There is no method in the example with that name. How did we get from `searchValue()` to `searchDish()`?

Comment: @flyingace I edited the question to change the component's method name from `searchValue` to `searchDish`. The edit is pending for peer review now. I tested the code and, yes, `searchValue` doesn't work. `searchDish` does. That should be a typo in the OP's description. I wanted to change all `searchDish` to `searchValue` but eventually did the opposite as that is easier.

Comment: Updated the question to reflect `searchDish()` vice `searchValue()`

Comment: hmm where do you get `shallow` from ? it's undefined for me in react-app tests

Answer (score 108, accepted):

The method can be mocked in this way:

```
it('handleNameInput', () => {
   let wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent/>);
   wrapper.instance().searchDish = jest.fn();
   wrapper.update();
   wrapper.instance().handleNameInput('BoB');
   expect(wrapper.instance().searchDish).toBeCalledWith('BoB');
})
```

You also need to call .update on the wrapper of the tested component in order to register the mock function properly.

The syntax error was coming from the wrong assingment (you need to assign the method to the instance). My other problems were coming from not calling `.update()` after mocking the method.

Comment: For me it throws and error with `expect(wrapper.searchDish)` — not a mock function or spy. Only when I change to `expect(wrapper.instance().searchDish)` it works properly.

Comment: @NikSumeiko even I was getting the same error, I stored the mock function into a variable and checked `toBeCalledWith` on that:
`const searchDishMock = jest.fn();
...
expect(searchDishMock).toBeCalledWith('BoB');
`

Comment: If `wrapper.update();` doesn't work, you can also try `wrapper.instance().forceUpdate();`

Comment: There is no "searchDish". The component method is "searchValue".

Comment: How does the `wrapper.update()` help here? [enzyme's documentation](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/update.html) doesn't say anything that `update()` can `register the mock function`.

Comment: Recalling subject's method is key step :)

Comment: What if you need to mock a method which is used in componentDidMount?  If you have to mount the component before you mock the method, will it work?

Comment: @mojave it will work if you manually call `componentDidMount` via `wrapper.instance().componentDidMount()`

Comment: where do you get `shallow` from ? it's undefined for me in react-app tests

Comment: NOTE: With React 16 and above, instance() returns null for stateless functional components. [docs](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/instance.html)

Comment: thanks for this answer, i totally forgot about `wrapper.update()`

Comment: I facing the same issue, but I am using functional component , always got 'TypeError: Cannot set property 'functionNotInUseEff' of null' error. 
```
  it('functionNotInUseEff', () => {
        let wrapper = mount(<Component1/>);
        wrapper.instance().functionNotInUseEff = jest.fn();
        wrapper.update();
        wrapper.instance().functionNotInUseEff('null');
        expect(wrapper.instance().functionNotInUseEff).toBeCalledWith('BoB');
     })
```

Answer (score 14):

Needs to be replaced `wrapper.update();` with `wrapper.instance().forceUpdate();`

Answer (score 0):

@Miha's answer worked with a small change:

```
it('handleNameInput', () => {
  let wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent/>);
  const searchDishMock = jest.fn();
  wrapper.instance().searchDish = searchDishMock;
  wrapper.update();
  wrapper.instance().handleNameInput('BoB');
  expect(searchDishMock).toBeCalledWith('BoB');
})
```

Comment: Does this still work? I'm using React 16 and enzyme 3.3.0 but the test doesn't pass. Besides, the [enzyme document](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/update.html) doesn't seem to suggest that `update` can register the mock function.

Comment: You don't need that `wrapper.update()` to get the tests to pass.

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this with React Test Library?