# How to test React component class methods

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have a React component that I am attempting to test some of its instance methods, but I am having trouble understanding how I am supposed to do it. The issue that is tripping me up is the fact that I am referring to `this.setState()` in the test and also `event.target` which are within a different context in my tests and therefore come back as `undefined`. What is the correct way to handle this?

Here is my component:

```
export default class MessageForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      message: '',
    };
  }

  onChange(event) { // testing this method
    const message = event.target.value; // event is undefined
    this.setState(prevState => Object.assign({}, prevState, { message })); // 'this' is undefined
  }

  handleOnClick(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // do some stuff here
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Form action="post">
        <TextArea onChange={this.onChange} />
        <ExpireButtonGroup />
        <SubmitButton onClick={this.handleOnClick}>
          <LockIcon src={lock} />
          Save
        </SubmitButton>
      </Form>
    );
  }
}
```

I am using Jest and Enzyme for testing. I am able to trigger the method using this test:

```
 test('it should allow a message to be typed', () => {
    const messageForm = shallow(<MessageForm />);
    expect(messageForm.instance().onChange())
  });
```

**-----------EDIT-----------**

I found this question: [How to mock React component methods with jest and enzyme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41830165/how-to-mock-react-component-methods-with-jest-and-enzyme)
... which seems to help, but I am still stuck with the error `cannot read property 'target' of undefined`. Here is my new test:

```
 test('it should handle a click event', () => {
    const mockEvent = {
      target: { dataset: { value: '60' }}
    };
    const button = shallow(<ExpireButton value={40}>Save</ExpireButton>);
    button.instance().handleOnClick(mockEvent) = jest.fn();
    button.update();
    button.simulate('click');
    expect(button.handleOnClick).toBeCalled();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You almost did it. In the instance just send the parameters as needed.

```
test('it should allow a message to be typed', () => {
const messageForm = shallow(<MessageForm />);
expect(messageForm.instance().onChange({target:"any text you want"}))
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I see that I can pass params but that still doesn't get me to a valid test because my `expect` doesn't really test anything. I believe I have progressed, but I am still not there yet. I have updated my question with more findings.

Comment: When you are calling .instance() method, you're just saying the test to call that method. So, you always will have to pass the parameters. This will help you to test the MessageForm component, that is after the onChange props is called; is the component working properly. To make sure the test is proper, while writing test suite for <TextArea> component, write a case where you'll test that the entire event is passed to the parent component i.e <MessageForm>. In this way, your entire test suite becomes valid.

Comment: For those who have searched for this answer more recently, be aware that in React 16 and above, instance() returns null for stateless functional components. [link](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/instance.html).