# How to mock React component events with jest and enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have read multiple SO answers regarding similar issues, but cannot see why things do not work for me.
I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41830165/how-to-mock-react-component-methods-with-jest-and-enzyme), and it does work as explained in the accepted answer, but not for simulated events.

This is the component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button
          onClick={this.handleClick}>
          Click me
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }

  func1() {
    console.log("In func1");
    this.func2();
  }

  func2() {
    console.log("In func2");
  }

  handleClick() {
    console.log("handleClick");
  }
}
```

and the following is the test file. test1 and test2 pass, test 3 and test4 fail.

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import App from 'components/App';

const handleClickSpy = jest.spyOn(App.prototype, 'handleClick');
const handleClickMock = jest.fn();

it('test 1 - call handleClick spy', () => {
  let wrapper = shallow(<App/>);
  wrapper.find('button').simulate('click');
  expect(handleClickSpy).toBeCalled();
});

it('test 2 - call func2 mock', () => {
  let wrapper = shallow(<App/>);
  const func2Mock = jest.fn();
  wrapper.instance().func2 = func2Mock;
  // wrapper.update();
  wrapper.instance().func1();
  expect(func2Mock).toBeCalled();
});

it('test 3 - call handleClick mock - take 1', () => {
  let wrapper = shallow(<App/>);
  wrapper.find('button').simulate('click');
  expect(handleClickMock).toBeCalled();
});

it('test 4 - call handleClick mock - take 2', () => {
  let wrapper = shallow(<App/>);
  const handleClickMock2 = jest.fn();
  wrapper.instance().handleClick = handleClickMock2;
  wrapper.update();
  wrapper.find('button').simulate('click');
  expect(handleClickMock2).toBeCalled();
});
```

The console.log printouts are the following (which mean that both mocks, in test3 and test4, didn't work):

```
  console.log src\components\App.js:25
    handleClick

  console.log src\components\App.js:16
    In func1

  console.log src\components\App.js:25
    handleClick

  console.log src\components\App.js:25
    handleClick
```

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer in [airbnb/enzyme #1081](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/1081)

These two work:

```
it('test 5 - call handleClick mock - take 3', () => {
  App.prototype.handleClick = jest.fn();
  let wrapper = shallow(<App/>);
  let { handleClick } = wrapper.instance();
  wrapper.find('button').simulate('click');
  expect(handleClick).toBeCalled();
});

it('test 6 - call handleClick mock - take 4', () => {
  App.prototype.handleClick = jest.fn();
  let wrapper = shallow(<App/>);
  let { handleClick } = wrapper.instance();
  wrapper.find('button').prop('onClick')();
  expect(handleClick).toBeCalled();
});
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? You are not mocking events.