# Jest testing onClick() gets error 'Expected mock function to have been called, but it was not called.'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to attempt some TDD and I thought I'd start with a simple login component. I'm struggling to test the function on a submit button.

I can test that the button is rendered and that when it is clicked that state is updated, so the function is being called in the component. The test can see the state is updated, but not that the function is being called.

I've boiled my code down to the most basic functionality that I can, I must not be able to see something! I removed all of the other tests for the Login Component so that I can try to narrow down the problem. I've tried a shallow() instead of a mount() but no joy. I want to write a more complicated test but I'm failing at even recognising that the fn has been called.

My test:

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import Login from './Login';

describe('when clicking the `submit` button', () => {
  const mockSubmit = jest.fn();

  const props = {
    handleBtnClick: mockSubmit
  };
  const wrapper = mount(<Login {...props} />);

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper.find('button.btn-submit').simulate('click');
  });

  it('renders the `submit` button', () => {
    expect(wrapper.find('button.btn-submit')).toExist();
  });

  it('when the submit button is clicked it updates `state`', () => {
    expect(wrapper.state().buttonClicked).toEqual(true);
  });

  it('calls the submit callback', () => {
    expect(mockSubmit).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

My Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class Login extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      buttonClicked: false
    }
  }


  handleBtnClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      buttonClicked: true 
    })
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.buttonClicked);
    return(
      <div>
        <h1>Login</h1> 
        <form>

          <div className="form-row">
            <button 
              type="submit" 
              className="btn-submit"
              onClick={this.handleBtnClick}
            >
              Submit
            </button>
          </div>      
        </form>
      </div>

    );
  }
}

export default Login;
```

Comment: Your mock is not called because you are sending it in with props.  And in your component, you are not calling the function on props.  Instead, you are calling the class method.

Comment: Aha, I just needed to search how to test a class method and I found my answer, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I needed to amend my search and add the keyword 'class method'. I was confused between the tutorials and articles I'd been reading. Using that I found this answer: [How to mock React component methods with jest and enzyme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41830165/how-to-mock-react-component-methods-with-jest-and-enzyme)

So the test:

```
it('calls the submit callback', () => {
    expect(mockSubmit).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

should be:

```
it('it calls the handleBtnClick method', () => {
      const mockSubmit= jest.fn();
      wrapper.instance().handleBtnClick= mockSubmit;
      wrapper.instance().handleBtnClick();
      expect(mockSubmit).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

And the props can be removed as that was the wrong tree to be barking up.