# onClick event with parameter being passed - Jest - React

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I am writing test cases for a small piece of code. I have a Tab component which has an onClick event. I am passing a parameter through the onClick function and somehow the test fails.

```
{_.map(TABS_LIST, (item, index) => (
    <Tab
        key={_.uniqueId()}
        panelId={`tab-${index}`}
        id={`tab-${index}`}
        onClick={() => this.handleTabClick(index)}
        selected={this.state.selectedTabIndex === index}
    >
    {item}
    </Tab>
))}

handleTabClick(e) {
    this.setState({
        selectedTabIndex: e
    });
}
```

The handleTabClick is already bound to this in the constructor.

This is the **test case**.

```
it('should onClick Tab', () => {

    wrapper.find('#tab-0').simulate('click', 0);


    expect(wrapper.instance().handleTabClick(0)).toHaveBeenCalledWith(0)
});
```

**Error**:

Error: expect(received).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function

Received has value: undefined

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, `toHaveBeenCalledWith` can only be used when you have a mocked function in `expect` call. more details [here](https://jest-bot.github.io/jest/docs/expect.html#tohavebeencalledwitharg1-arg2-).

Since in your scenario here, your not calling a callback, but setting the state, you can check if value of `selectedTabIndex` in component state has been set with new index after the click simulation. you can use the [`wrapper.state()`](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/state.html) method for the same.

Comment: I already checked it and it works. But is there any way to test that the function has been called with the param?

Comment: you can try mocking the component method. as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41830165/how-to-mock-react-component-methods-with-jest-and-enzyme)