# Mock a internal function in functional component test jest and Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

Can we mock internal function in functional component testing using jest and Enzyme Like we previously do in the class component. For example

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  handleNameInput = (value) => {
    searchDish(value);
  };

  searchDish = (value) => {
    //Do something
  }
  render() {
    return (<div></div>)
  }
}
```

I want to mock search dish. As we do in class component testing as mentioned in the questions 
[How to mock React component methods with jest and enzyme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41830165/how-to-mock-react-component-methods-with-jest-and-enzyme)

Comment: I just here take example of a functional component for testing just wanted to ask for testing either I getting correct param in search value so I wanted to mock searchDish. is this possible in functional component testing.